# WINEHQ - wine_gecko won't init - HTML Rendering disabled

Tags: linux, wine

I'm currently trying to get a windows compiled program to work through Wine to run on Linux and MacOSX.

When I run the program through wine, it prompts me to install Gecko which I do.  Later on in the program, it attempts to use MSHTML to render HTML but I get these error messages on my console instead.

err:mshtml:init_xpcom NS_InitXPCOM2 failed: 80004005
err:mshtml:HTMLDocument_Create Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE
fixme:ole:CoCreateInstance no instance created for interface {00000000-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} of class {25336920-03f9-11cf-8fd0-00aa00686f13}, hres is 0x80040111

I'm using Wine 1.1.34 and a similar bug was supposedly fixed in 1.1.33
http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12578

I've been at this all afternoon, is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks,
  Nick

Comment: Essentially you are running an app in Wine, and it isn't working as expected.  The errors you have are related to Gecko not being able to find the class HTMLDocument_Create.  This is odd because this will work under windows.  There is a solution to this, I just don't know it.

Comment: -Wine_Gecko is installed at $WINEPREFIX/drive_c/windows/system32/gecko/1.0.0

-My program also contains a web browser which seems to work fine rendering HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with winetricks wine doesn't support com so creating the com component will cause this error.  There is no fix.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, I did a bit more research into the subject myself and I came to the same conclusion, I just forgot I had posted here.  I'll re-write it to avoid that specific com object.

Answer (score 0):

So if you type "wine iexplore.exe" does it open up the wine version of internet explorer (gecko)?

You said this program was "windows compiled". Are you the one that compiled it? Did you use visual studio?

If this is a .NET application, you'll need to use mono to run it.

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: -yes, it opens IE with gecko
-I meant to say installed instead of compiled
-no, its not .net

Comment: So your trying to run a program that was installed in windows from linux? Have you tried installing the application in linux using wine? Who knows what dll's and registry keys your missing if you did not install it under wine. Can you tell us what program it is your trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

Try [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks).

Follow these steps:

```
wget http://www.kegel.com/wine/winetricks
chmod a+x winetricks
env WINEPREFIX=yourwineprefix ./winetricks gecko
```

winetricks is my favorite wine tool and allows you to fix large array of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a very similar issue because I was using 64-bit Wine and only installed the 64-bit Gecko. It turns out that sometimes you may need both 64-bit and 32-bit Gecko.
The error in my case was "`01ff:err:mshtml:create_document_object Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE`".

After installing both 64-bit and 32-bit Gecko, the problem went away and rendering started working.

I used the latest Gecko installers from https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko
and installed them both using `msiexec /i <installer>.msi`.